# Getting java.lang.ClassCastException while trying to develop an android application

Tags: java, android

I have this exception "java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.utility.TablePlussAndroid"
I do not understand why... thanks a lot for your help

```
package com.tableplustablet;
private com.utility.TablePlusAndroid session;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    // ...

    // get session from Application                        
    session =  (TablePlusAndroid) this.getApplication(); // <--EXCEPTION
    session.setUserKey(userKey);
} 

// -------------------------------------------------------------

package com.utility;
import android.app.Application;

 //Save User Data in  application's context
 public class TablePlusAndroid extends Application{
private Long userKey;
private String userName;
private Long currentTableKey;  

    public Long getCurrentTableKey() {
        return currentTableKey;
}

    public void setCurrentTableKey(Long currentTableKey) {
        this.currentTableKey = currentTableKey;
    }
    public Long getUserKey(){ return userKey;}
    public void setUserKey(Long key){ userKey=key;}
    public String getUserName() { return userName; }
    public void setUserName(String userName) { this.userName = userName; }  
}
```

Comment: Can you point to the exact line of code that is giving the exception? That would make it easier to get help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use your application class in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

It should look like this:

```
<application android:name="application.package.and.class">
    <activity .... />
</application>
```

Comment: thanks! I missed to put android:name (it was a merge with another applicaion)